# 2 nic cards in ubuntu PC, one to router, one to win7 pc, make connected pc on router talk to win7 on 2nd nic

Tags: ubuntu, ping, local-area-network

There are 2 win7 pc, 2 100 mb/s routers and 1 ubuntu 12.04 pc.

I scanned a diagram of the Lan setup with IP's

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-uChF5IIApj8/UOrFVvJYMiI/AAAAAAAAEV0/lyAJAvYks9k/s1024/lan.jpeg

I can not ping from first win7 to second win7 but second win7 can ping first win7 pc.

Ubuntu pc has 2 nic, 100mb/s ethernet nic to router, gigabyte nic direct to gigabyte nic in win7 pc. Ubuntu PC has "share this connection to other pc" on. that nic is eth2 and is 10.42.0.1

2nd Win7 pc is assigned 10.42.0.19

What I want is the win7 pc on second router to ping the other win7 pc on the gigabyte lan.

The ubuntu PC can ping both win7 pc's.
The first win7 pc can ping ubuntu pc but not the second win7 pc
The second win7 pc can ping the ubuntu pc and the first win7 pc

This is the route command in ubuntu pc

```
   scott@scott-P5QC:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         wr850g.hr.cox.n 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth2
scott@scott-P5QC:~$ 

scott@scott-P5QC:~$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth2
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth2
```

So any ideas? I did this odd design so that I can have gigabit lan working between the ubuntu pc and the second win7 pc.

Comment: Reading your question fast. Can you disable windows firewall on THE SECOND Win7 machine and try to ping it again?

Comment: I just tried turning off firewall it does not help. I have modified the scope rule to at least have it work a little

Comment: shows the ping fail from first win7 to second win7https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-hNUvIbIiDmI/UOrTV9kK9yI/AAAAAAAAEWE/BudmA2vUkoA/s811/pinwin7%2520to%2520ubuntu.png

Comment: show success from second win7 to first win7https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-NnC6VA4io70/UOrTV-8yp-I/AAAAAAAAEWI/RCnKdqcsjPg/s1040/ping%2520second%2520win7.png

Comment: shows the ping fail from first win7 to second somehow link broke   https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/aeEz7poA0K-c0qy60q2YI9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Comment: Destination port unreachable. Seems to me like a firewall issue. Even though you've disabled it, there is something blocking the ping request.

Comment: I fixed it.
I installed firestarter a firewall for linux.
Ran thru the setup
Now I can ping from win7 to win7 both ways!
I started to think that ubuntu PC was blocking incoming traffic meant to go to 10.42.0.19
And thought maybe a firewall program could make it work.
Wonder how it removed the incoming traffic block?
Any ideas on what it did?

Link shows first win7 now pinging second win7. using chrome remote desktop makes it easy to sit at one pc and see it work.

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/28yAAk8QCMs07hZKyw8It9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Comment: Well, it is broken again, DHCP for eth0 is now off for some reason. Firestarter is giving error cant start DHCP, so my second win7 PC has assigned address 169.254.113.96 or something like that. It was working then it just quit.

Comment: scott@scott-P5QC:~$ firestarter
scott@scott-P5QC:~$ gksu firestarter
Firewall started
Firewall started
Failed to start DHCP server
Firewall script saved as /etc/firestarter/firewall
Firewall started
Failed to start DHCP server

Comment: well firestarter will let me ping, but first win7 can NOT go to any shares on the second win7 pc, second win7 pc can open shares on the first win7 pc. Firestarter also has a major unfixed bug  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firestarter/+bug/43784

Answer (score 0):

solved by installing webmin. Then used it to reset iptables.
Seriously great tool for administering the firewall. 
Webmin told me 2 rules were in the iptables which it could not understand, so I save iprules to a file, did a reset and all 3 pc can share files.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-server.html

scott@scott-P5QC:~$ sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.580_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package webmin.
(Reading database ... 229686 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking webmin (from webmin_1.580_all.deb) ...
Setting up webmin (1.580) ...
Webmin install complete. You can now login to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
as root with your root password, or as any user who can use sudo
to run commands as root.
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
scott@scott-P5QC:~$

shows what it looks like
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/oX1xo7I07W38s4C7Laftv9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink